# Rewriting multiple wordpress installs on the same domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have two Wordpress installations I need to serve:

- `/` to `/var/www/sales`
- `/blog/` to `/var/www/blog`

There are a couple caveats:

1. `/` is a brand new installation.
2. `/blog` is being migrated over from another server.

We're using Apache 2 with a basic (default?) configuration to serve files from `/var/www/`.

How do we server these applications so that legacy `/blog` URLs are served exactly the same as they were (i.e `/blog/category/yada` -> `/blog/category/yada`), while **all other requests** are handled by the brand new installation.

Comment: Sounds like you need to specify an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) for `/blog` in your main config or VirtualHost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your permissions are good if your root is ./sales/ and you're trying to go to ./blog

Second,

Alias /blog "/var/www/blog" (? i'm not totally sure I understand your'e set up)

```
<directory "/var/www/blog">
(Whatever rules you're after)
allow from all
order allow, deny
allow override all
</directory>
```

you could also do it with a symlink in the install and add

```
<directory /var/www/>
options +followsymlinks
</directory>
```

Sorry in advance for typing like someone who got 2 hours of sleep.

Comment: it's two wordpress installs in subdirectories on the same domain without using wordpress' multisite management. But `Alias` works.